# The position of Oracle Exception matters?

Tags: sql, oracle, exception, plsql, return

In the function `test2` below, if i put the `RETURN V_VALUE;` after 
EXCEPTION Clause, when executing code2, system exception `ORA-06503: Function returned without value` error occurs.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION TEST2
    (P1 IN VARCHAR2)
RETURN NUMBER AS V_VALUE NUMBER;
BEGIN
    SELECT(
        SELECT 1/TO_NUMBER(P1)
        FROM DUAL
        )
    INTO V_VALUE
    FROM DUAL;

    --RETURN V_VALUE; 

    EXCEPTION   
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
      RETURN NULL;  

    RETURN V_VALUE; --if I put RETURN clause after EXCEPTION, "ORA-06503: Function returned without value" raised
END;
/

SELECT TEST2('1') FROM DUAL;
```

However, when I put `RETURN V_VALUE;` before the EXCEPTION Clause, the select statement returns `1` as expected.

Should the position of Exception be at end of function body?

Answer (score 3):

The structure of a PL/SQL block is defined in [the PL/SQL documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/block.htm#LNPLS01303). The body of a block comprises one or more statements optionally followed by an exception handler.  The end of the EXCEPTIONS section is the end of the block; nothing comes after that.

The RETURN statement is the last line of the regular body. So it must go before the EXCEPTION block.

Generally speaking when we do a thing one way and get a compilation error, then do the thing a different way and get the expected result we can consider that a pretty big clue as to what is the correct approach to take ;-)